# Writing a pyspark reduced dataframe to Neo4j using py2neo

Tags: pyspark, neo4j, py2neo

I have a dataframe in pyspark with 2 columns (col1 and col2), col2 is a list of rows (dataframe is reduced on col1). Now I want to write this dataframe to neo4j using py2neo. How do I write and format the cypher query string? My query if I was to write the dataframe using spark connector looks like this -

```
query_sparkneo4j_connector = "MERGE (d:Node1 {Node1: event.col1}) \
        FOREACH (i in event.col2 | \
            CREATE (c:Node2 {Prop1: i.xx, Prop2: i.yy}) \
            CREATE (c)-[:Rel1]->(d));"
```

I tried two approaches but they don't work -

**Approach1:**

```
query1_py2neo = '''MERGE (d:Node1 {{Node1: '{col1val}'}})
        FOREACH (i in {col2val} |
            CREATE (c:Node2 {{Prop1: i.xx, Prop2: i.yy}})
            CREATE (c)-[:Rel1]->(d));'''

for row in df.collect():
    col1_val = row["col1_name"]
    col2_val = row["col2_name"] #this is a list of Row type
    graph.run(query1_py2neo.format(col1val=col1_val, col2val=col2_val))
```

Gives the error below -

```
py2neo.errors.ClientError: [Statement.SyntaxError] Variable `xx` not defined (line 2, column 31 (offset: 71))
"        FOREACH (i in [Row(xx='somevalue', yy='someothervalue')] |"
```

**Approach2:**

```
query2_py2neo = '''UNWIND $batch as row
        MERGE (d:Node1 {{Node1: row.col1_name}})
        FOREACH (i in row.certificates |
            CREATE (c:Node2 {{Prop1: i.xx, Prop2: i.yy}})
            CREATE (c)-[:Rel1]->(d));'''

graph.run(query2_py2neo, batch=df1)
```

Gives the error below -

```
TypeError: Values of type <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'> are not supported
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here seems to be that the parameters you are passing as `col2val` are of unexpected types. If you can convert your DataFrame so that `col2val` is a list of dicts you can use the following query

```
MERGE (d:Node1 {Node1: $col1val})
WITH d
UNWIND $col2val AS property_dict
CREATE (c:Node2)
SET c = property_dict
CREATE (c)-[:Rel1]->(d)
```

Comment: I have columns of different datatypes, one of which is array<string> and hence I'm unable to add it as a dict in the dataframe like you suggested. However, if I convert the col2val to a list of maps while passing it to the query, I'm unable to access the keys as property_dict.key_name. I cannot have the query as SET c = property_dict but need access to the key value pairs within the map to use in the query. The actual query I have is more complex than the one mentioned in the question and need more breaking down of one of the values in the dict (which is an array of strings).

Comment: Is there any way to run the query_sparkneo4j_connector I mentioned in the question using py2neo? In spark-neo4j connector this query works fine taking each row in the df as event and accessing the columns of that row.